# Build Reasoning System in Python for Procedure recommendations

Tags: deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, stanford-nlp, reasoning, knowledge-graph

I want to develop a reasoning system that would provide steps/procedures to resolve a issue that a  user is facing. 
examples: if a user types "please reset my password" the reasoning system should search in the knowledge if it has steps for resolution of the same and would then return all the steps like "go to url"->"click forgot password"->"enter new password" etc. and  If a user types another query like "Please unlock my account" the reasoning system should go through existing knowledge and use the available steps to recommend to user. the resolution steps can overlap with the steps recommended for password reset issue. like "go to url" could be common step for both the queries.

Based on my research on the same I believe i need to create a knowledge graph of all the resolution steps first. But if you could please advise on how to proceed with it as there are several ways to represent a knowledge, but I'm unable to see how to create a knowledge base/graph of linked resolution steps and how to reason through it. I use python for my work hence, any guidance would really be helpful.